# Não estou conseguindo fazer o somatório da coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Quero fazer o somatório da coluna Valor, sei que para usar o SUM() tenho que usar também o GROUP BY, só que não estou conseguindo fazer o somatório. Não sei quais campos tenho que colocar no GROUP BY.

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.sales_office AS kam, z.customer,g.sales_order,
d.nfnum, d.vlr_liq_nf AS valor FROM TPL_GUARDA g 
LEFT JOIN TPL_COLETAS c     ON g.SALES_ORDER   = c.SALES_ORDER 
LEFT JOIN humo h            ON h.HANDLING_UNIT = g.handling_unit 
LEFT JOIN DANFE_DELIVERY dd ON dd.delivery     = h.delivery 
LEFT JOIN danfe d           ON d.nfnum         = dd.nfnum 
LEFT JOIN zzcustmon z       ON z.sales_order   = g.sales_order 
where c.dt_exp is null and d.nfnum is not null and z.delivery is not null 
GROUP BY
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, no `group by` devem entrar todos os campos que não foram o `sum`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.sales_office AS kam, z.customer, g.sales_order, d.nfnum, SUM(d.vlr_liq_nf) AS valor
FROM TPL_GUARDA g 
LEFT JOIN TPL_COLETAS c     ON g.SALES_ORDER   = c.SALES_ORDER 
LEFT JOIN humo h            ON h.HANDLING_UNIT = g.handling_unit 
LEFT JOIN DANFE_DELIVERY dd ON dd.delivery     = h.delivery 
LEFT JOIN danfe d           ON d.nfnum         = dd.nfnum 
LEFT JOIN zzcustmon z       ON z.sales_order   = g.sales_order 
WHERE c.dt_exp IS NULL
  AND d.nfnum IS NOT NULL
  AND z.delivery IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY z.sales_office, z.customer, g.sales_order, d.nfnum
```

---

Em comentário foi dito que o campo a ser somado é do tipo `varchar2`. Garantindo que mesmo assim seriam inteiro salvos como texto, pode usar o [`to_number`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php):

```
SUM(TO_NUMBER(d.vlr_liq_nf))
```

---

Como citado em comentário, os valores no banco de dados estavam sendo separados por vírgulas, o que não é aceito pelo *oracle* como um número válido; bastaria então dar um `replace` e trocar a *vírgula* por um *ponto* (caracter aceito):

```
SUM(REPLACE(d.vlr_liq_nf,',','.'))
```

Comment: Tentei executar o código e deu o erro ORA-01722: invalid number.

Comment: `d.vlr_liq_nf` não é um campo numérico?

Comment: São os preços dos materiais que ficam nela

Comment: @GuilhermeWayne, poderia compartilhar as definições dos campos da coluna na pergunta, lembrando que os campos de somatório só funcionam em campos numéricos.

Comment: O campo que estou querendo somar é do tipo varchar2. Acabei de olhar aqui. Pensei que era numerico. Tem como fazer a soma dele?

Comment: @GuilhermeWayne, a resposta (editada) ajudou??

Comment: O TO_NUMBER não funcionou, depois de quebrar a cabeça tentando, descobri que o oracle não trata a virgula como separação de valores, o correto é usar ponto. Então por mais que eu tentasse converter o valor com TO_NUMBER, não funcionaria. Então usei o REPLACE para substituir a virgula por ponto, e então funcionou

Comment: @GuilhermeWayne entendi. bom, vou alterar a resposta e adicionar isso que você passou, mas se preferir, poste uma resposta dizendo o que resolveu e marque como aceita.. ideal é que a pergunta [não fique sem resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Comment: @rLinhares acabei de fazer isso

Answer (score 0):

Usa a função SUM que vai resolver o seu problema.

```
SELECT SUM (d.vlr_liq_nf) AS valor
FROM TPL_GUARDA g 
LEFT JOIN TPL_COLETAS c     ON g.SALES_ORDER   = c.SALES_ORDER 
LEFT JOIN humo h            ON h.HANDLING_UNIT = g.handling_unit 
LEFT JOIN DANFE_DELIVERY dd ON dd.delivery     = h.delivery 
LEFT JOIN danfe d           ON d.nfnum         = dd.nfnum 
LEFT JOIN zzcustmon z       ON z.sales_order   = g.sales_order
```

Desse modo, vai te retornar apenas o resultado que você precisa, a soma dos valores dessa coluna. Verifique o tipo da coluna é numérico.

Comment: Danyel, snippet é para códigos HTML, CSS e JAVASCRIPT. O SO deixa bem claro para que serve. Revise a sua resposta.

Comment: Não deu certo, ainda continua dando o erro de Invalid Number. Esse campo armazena os valores dos materiais, armazena valores de dinheiro

Comment: Esse erro, Invalid Number, normalmente acontece quando tenta fazer uma operação( "+" , "-" , "/" , "*") usando tipo de dados String ("9 + 1") Invalid Number.

Comment: Caro amigo ciclista @DanyelPires, ele esta perguntando sobre a soma da coluna, não a média .

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, no oracle, a tratação de vírgula é diferente, virgula não quer dizer virgula. Estava dando o erro Invalid Number, por causa da virgula, o oracle não conseguia fazer a conversão. Então usei o replace para substituir a virgula por um ponto, e usei um outro select para que não precise usar o group by. Segue o código funcionando:

```
 SELECT SUM(REPLACE(valor,',','.')) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT z.sales_office AS 
 kam, z.customer,g.sales_order,
 d.nfnum, d.vlr_liq_nf AS valor FROM TPL_GUARDA g 
 LEFT JOIN TPL_COLETAS c     ON g.SALES_ORDER   = c.SALES_ORDER 
 LEFT JOIN humo h            ON h.HANDLING_UNIT = g.handling_unit 
 LEFT JOIN DANFE_DELIVERY dd ON dd.delivery     = h.delivery 
 LEFT JOIN danfe d           ON d.nfnum         = dd.nfnum 
 LEFT JOIN zzcustmon z       ON z.sales_order   = g.sales_order 
 where c.dt_exp is null and d.nfnum is not null and z.delivery is not null)
```

Comment: `SUM(REPLACE(valor,',','.'))` esse `valor` é um alias ou o nome do campo? se for alias, acredito que dará erro de execução

Comment: É um alias que esta dentro do segundo select. Não esta dando erro, pois já testei e implementei no sistema. Antes de testar também pensei que iria dar erro, mas não deu. Funcionou corretamente.